# Capture combination key event in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

When the user presses the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> keys, I want my form to respond by calling up a message box.

How do I do this in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Handle the `KeyDown` event and have something like:

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
{
    MessageBox.Show("My message");
}
```

The event handler has to be on the Main Form and you need to set the `KeyPreview` property to `true`. This can be done in design mode from the properties dialog.

Comment: Don't think it works. I tried a lot of times, but the MessageBox never come up

Comment: it does work on a `keydown` event for a form. Sorry. I was putting the above code in  the `keydown` event of the control hosted in the form, which was why it didn't work

Comment: The Event is firing but the condition is always becoming false.

Answer (score 11):

In case you want to use multiple modifiers `KeyEventArgs` also has boolean values to indicate if CTRL, ALT or SHIFT is pressed.

Example:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.Alt && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.F12)
        MessageBox.Show("My message");
}
```

In this example the messagebox is show if CTRL, ALT, SHIFT and F12 are pressed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple modifiers keys ( In KeyDown event)

```
 if (e.Control && e.Shift)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
                {
                    // Your code goes here

                }
            }
```