# Capturing Ctrl + Shift + P key stroke in a C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture combination key event in a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062587)

I need to perform a particular operation when (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) keys are pressed.

How can I capture this in my [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) application?

Comment: Best way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms/400325#400325

Comment: Do you want any Ctrl+Shift+P key combination to perform the operation regardless of which application has focus? Or do you simply want a "global shortcut" for this operation in your own application? That answer will determine which of the below answers is best; the P/Invoke answer is better if you want to "grab" the keys from another app using a taskbar app or service, while a KeyDown handler is preferred for in-app keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Personally I think this is the simplest way.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this will capture keydown from form n... if you place a usercontrol on form and try to do the same...handler won't get fired

Comment: It will ,if you set the form's KeyPreview property to true.

Comment: Its really worked for me. Please add this note for everyone that we have to set the Forms-> keypreview - > True.

Answer (score 4):

The following is not only a way to capture keystroke on your form, but it is in fact a way to add global Windows shortcuts.

**1.** Import needed libraries at the top of your class:

```
// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

**2.** Add a *field* in your [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) class that will be a reference for the hotkey in your code:

```
const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
```

**3.** Register the hotkey (in the constructor of your Windows Forms for instance):

```
// Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
// Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
// ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 6, (int)'P');
```

**4.** Handle the typed keys by adding the following method in your Windows Forms class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID) {
        // My hotkey has been typed

        // Do what you want here
        // ...
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Still relevant and works today in 2020. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the KeyDownEvent with a lambda event handler:

[Here is some more information about KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx). Read the article and think about the scope in which you want to have this behavior.

```
this.KeyDown += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("pressed");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetKeyboardState API via [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). It returns an array representing the state of each virtual key recognised by Windows. If I'm not mistaken, you can cast the Keys enum to a byte and use it as an index as follows:

```
byte[] keys = new byte[256];
GetKeyboardState(keys);
bool isCtrlPressed = (keys[(byte)Keys.ControlKey] == 1);
```

-

Resources:

- [P/Invoke definition](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeyboardstate)
- MSDN documentation: [GetKeyboardState function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646299%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Oops, screwed up the code. It should be: bool isCtrlPressed = (keys[(byte)Keys.ControlKey] == 1);

Comment: is it that complicated? There should be simpler way in c#

Comment: @Poly: You can edit your post.