# How to capture combination key event?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, events

In **C#**, it was written like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

[Capturing Ctrl + Shift + P key stroke in a C# Windows Forms application [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650915/capturing-ctrl-shift-p-key-stroke-in-a-c-sharp-windows-forms-application)

I tried to emulate the **way** they wrote it in **C#** to **Delphi XE8** but it doesn't seemed to work:

```
procedure TForm12.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) and (Key = 53) then
    ShowMessage('You pressed "ctrl + s"');
end;
```

> Note: The **TForm.KeyPreview Troperty** is set to **true**

How can I capture that combination key event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key you are looking for, <kbd>S</kbd>, has code `$53`. The key you specified has code `53` and is the number <kbd>5</kbd>. The difference is the `$` which signifies hexadecimal.

You'd avoid such silly mistakes, and make the code much clearer, if you let the compiler do the work:

```
Key = ord('S')
```

You really don't want to use magic constants in your program. That is very important.

Note that `Key` is a [virtual key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx) and the convention is that for the 26 keys of the Latin alphabet, they are represented by the ordinal value of the *uppercase* letter.

The message already passes the state of the modifier keys in the [`Shift`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TShiftState) argument, so it is idiomatic to write the test  as follows:

```
if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (Key = ord('S')) then
```

Your test using `GetKeyState` does work well, but it's just not idiomatic.

Note that this test, which matches that in the question will, ignores the state of the other modifier keys. Indeed, the C# code in the question also ignores the state of the <kbd>ALT</kbd> modifier.

So you may want a true test for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> you must also check that the other modifiers are up:

```
if ([ssCtrl] = Shift*[ssCtrl, ssShift, ssAlt]) and (Key = ord('S')) then
```

All this said, it's usually much easier to manage your shortcuts using actions. This will allow you to specify shortcuts directly, and let the framework detect the low level key events that make up a shortcut. What's more actions allow you to centralise handling of the actions behind buttons and menus without you repeating yourself.

Comment: Sir David Heffernan, you're such a legend. Thank you for a very concise answer.

Comment: @David - I'm surprised that you would say "GetKeyState() does work well".  Using **GetKeyState()** is potentially unreliable since the key state may be different at the time that the event is processed than it was at the time of the input event itself (which is exactly why the state at the time of the event is provided *with* the event).

Comment: @Deltics Not so. You are thinking of `GetAsyncKeyState`. From the docs: *An application calls GetKeyState in response to a keyboard-input message. This function retrieves the state of the key when the input message was generated.*

Comment: @David - yikes, you're right.  Failure in the memory banks on that one.  Having said that, it's still the case that GetKeyState() will only "work well" if the event is called in response to an actual keyboard input event and there is no way to (absolutely) guarantee this.  If the handler were to be called directly, the fact that the implementation ignores the contracted TShiftState parameter is not very helpful.

Comment: @Deltics Well, I think it's reasonable to assume that this event is attached to the appropriate event. Do note that I advised the asker to use shift state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use actions to automate shortcuts. Drop in a `TActionManager` and add a `TAction` to it. On that action, assign a `Name`, `Caption`, and an `OnExecute` event handler, and most importantly a value for `ShortCut`. This can be a string representing the keystrokes, in your case `Ctrl+Shift+P`. Then, you can either assign that action to various controls, or call it like `MyAction.Execute`.

Comment: After an hour, I realized that using TActionManager is much efficient than my previous idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi you use the `Shift: TShiftState` to check which 'shift'-keys are pressed.

As pointed out in comments your error is that the key value for letter `s` is not decimal `53`, but hexadecimal `53`, iow `$53`in Delphi syntax.

I first thought you also wanted to check for the `shift` key as in the referenced source of your inspiration, in which case you can test for the *exclusive* combination as follows:

```
procedure TForm15.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = $53) and ([ssCtrl, ssShift] = Shift) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('You pressed "ctrl + shift + s"');
    Key := 0; // optional
  end;
end;
```

You may or may not want to clear the `Key` parameter to prevent further action by the control with focus.

Rereading your question after another comment, you seem to want to detect only the `Ctrl + s` combination, in which case the *exclusive* condition test becomes

```
  if (Key = $53) and ([ssCtrl] = Shift) then
```

I recommed to be precise (exclusive) in the shift state test, because the shift state includes not only the `Shift`, `Ctrl`and `Alt` keys but also mouse buttons and some gestures.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TShiftState) on `TShiftState` provides other possible values of `Shift` to check for.

Finally, as @David Heffernan points out in his answer, instead of a magic constant (`$53`) for the key test, use `Ord('S')`.

Comment: The problem was not related to shift state. The `GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0` works fine, albeit is not idiomatic. The problem was `53` instead of `ord('S') = $53`.

Comment: @David Thanks for the comment. Yes I saw that but forgot to specifically mention it.

Comment: The code doesn't intend to check for shift key. `ShowMessage('You pressed "ctrl + s"');` The asker is attempting to detect Ctrl + S.