# How to detect the Ctrl+P key combination in Embarcadero C++Builder

Tags: key, combinations, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder 10.4.1. I want to use the Ctrl+P combination to open the PrintDialog but I don't know how to detect the Ctrl+P key combination.

Comment: If you can use Delphi code for inspiration, enter `[delphi] Ctrl+P` in the search box. There are plenty of examples. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33705163/2292722

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OnKeyDown` event it returns 16 bit extended key code (so you got also num pad arrows and other stuff)...

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
    {
//  Caption=Key; // this will print aktually pressed key code to caption
    if ((Key=='P')&&(Shift.Contains(ssCtrl)))
        Caption="print"; // here open your dialog
    }
```

so for keys test the `Key` value and for special keys and buttons test `Shift` (you know shift,ctrl,alt,mouse buttons)

There is also:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::FormShortCut(TWMKey &Msg, bool &Handled)
    {
    static bool ctrl=false;
    if (Msg.CharCode=='P')
        {
        Caption="print2";
        Handled=true;
        }
    ctrl=(Msg.CharCode==VK_LCONTROL)||(Msg.CharCode==VK_RCONTROL);
    }
```

Which has major priority over other key/mouse events. However it can only recognize the `TWMKey` codes which I do not like and for unsuported key combinations you need to do a hack like I did in example above...

In case you want more combinations or keep track of which keys are pressed (movement controls...) then you have to implement a key map table something like this:

- [Computer Graphics: Moving in the world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477602/2521214)

Comment: To use the `OnKey(Down|Up)` events at the Form level, you usually need to set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to true, otherwise keystrokes will be sent only to the focused control and not to the Form itself.

Comment: Remy, making this addition was important and I didn't know about it. This addition helped to make the app's behavior more consistent. Thanks.

Comment: Spektre, I used a variation of your first suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @RemyLebeau good point (I knew about it just forgot to mention ...) just need to add that other key events must not change the `Key` parameter when `P` is pressed (its similar to `Handled`)

Answer (score 2):

Place a [`TActionList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnList.TActionList) or [`TActionManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMan.TActionManager) onto your Form, and then add the standard [`TPrintDlg`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdActns.TPrintDlg) action to it.  You can then set the action's `ShortCut` property to <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>, and the VCL will invoke the action for you automatically when that keyboard shortcut is pressed:

> TPrintDlg is the standard action for displaying a print dialog.
>
> Add TPrintDlg to an action list to add a print dialog to your application. Controls such as menu items and tool buttons linked to this action cause the application to display the print dialog (TPrintDialog) when invoked. Write an [OnAccept](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdActns.TCommonDialogAction.OnAccept) event handler to perform the actual printing when the user clicks OK. You can read details about the user's selections in the dialog from the [Dialog](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdActns.TPrintDlg.Dialog) property.

See Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Handling VCL Actions Using an Action List](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Handling_VCL_Actions_Using_an_Action_List)

[Handling VCL Actions Using an Action Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Handling_VCL_Actions_Using_an_Action_Manager)