# Multiple key presses in one case

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

So I'm making an application that will use a lot of keys on the keyboard, and I want to put them all in a switch-case. My problem is, the application also needs to detect key combinations like Shift + 9 for brackets, etc. I tried this:

```
case Keys.Shift & Keys.D9:
```

But I found out that the '&' operator is unary or binary, and no other operators seem to work.

Can I solve this by making a nested switch-case like:

```
case Keys.Shift:
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
         case Keys.D9:

         break;
    }
    break;
```

Or is this bad practise? Because I don't really want to make a big list of if-else statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `case (Keys.Shift && Keys.D9)`?

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062587/capture-combination-key-event-in-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: @maniak1982 Yes, I get the error that the operator can't be used.

Comment: The other comment suggests switching to an if statement, which I agree may be the right choice here.

Comment: @ssimeonov Yes, I know that I can solve this with if- and if-else statements. I was only wondering if this could be solved with a switch-statement, since that would be more convenient in this case.

Comment: I don't think that nested switches will be more convenient way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't nest switch-case but use if-statements.

Also, to check for key combinations I would suggest you use something like this:

```
if ((ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.D9:
            //do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, If I understand correctly, I would need a switch-case for when the user presses Shift and one for when the user doesn't press Shift?

Comment: `ModifierKeys` indicates which of the modifier keys is in a pressed state. The if-statement in my example checks if this is the shift-key. So I would nest a couple of if statements for the relevant modifier keys (alt, shift, control) and in the final `else` you can have your regular switch-case for when only 1 key is pressed.