# Keyboard shortcuts in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, key-bindings

I want to use the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the current form, but there is also one condition: if the user presses a similar combination like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd>, it shouldn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture combination key event in a Windows Forms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062587/capture-combination-key-event-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: Do you want this shortcut within a particular control or the entire application?

Comment: particular control

Comment: Alt+X, C are *two* keystrokes.  You would have to start a Timer when you see Alt+X to wait for the C to appear.  Setting the Interval for this Timer to a suitable value is near impossible.  Make it too short and the user loses badly, having the UI go up in smoke.  The more the user is impaired, the worse he loses.  Make it too long and the user is greatly confuzzled why Alt+X does not appear to work well.  Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

The form/control has an event called key press and key down. In the properties window input 'Form1_KeyPress'. This will run the method below

```
void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == //KeyCode for alt && e.KeyChar == //KeyCode for x)
    {
        //run code here
    }
}
```